# Mapstruct - there's a way to monitor generation times?

Tags: mapstruct

I work on a large project with ~30 mapper classes and some of them contain a lot of mapper declarations.

I was able to split the annotation processor task from the rest of build process on gradle and it took ~5 minutes to generate the mappers. (PC with i7 processor and SSD)

There's a way to monitor code generation times of mappers? I need to investigate where it took too much time and make some tuning.

Currently I'm on mapstruct 1.1 (updating to 1.2 doesn't help).

Answer (score 1):

That's quite slow. We already had a report for a performance decrees on Java 9 (see Issue [#1378](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1378)). However, that project has ~5200 classes with ~400 mappers. On Java 8 it took ~90 seconds, whereas on Java 9 ~150 seconds.

Gradle is a normal java process, so you can do a normal Java monitoring. If you want you can send us the sample so we can analyse it, or you can send us the analysis.

You can also try with PR [#1379](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1379) using [jiptack.io](https://jitpack.io/) for a reference

Comment: I'm on java 8 actually. I suspect the performance decreases when there are a lot of definition in a single interface, in one I have ~540 methods in one class

Comment: OK, that is quite some methods you have :). In any case if you can do some benchmarking and share us your results we can improve the performance

Comment: Just a note after some time spent in reworking our mappers, we have splitted some large mappers into many smaller mappers and the build time is now is less than half than before. So the suggestion is to prefer many small mapper to large mappers.

Comment: This is good to know. Thanks for letting me know. We should probably investigate why this is the case. If you want to can open up an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/)